# node.js form elements array

Tags: arrays, node.js, post

How to parse form elements array in NodeJS ?

Like in PHP we get `$_POST['answers']` for form elements with names: `answers[0], answers[1], answer[2] .... answers[n]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my own solution for this, for example I am getting data in `var obj`:

```
console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

var obj = { 
    'answer[\'test\']': 'first',
    'answer[\'2\']': 'second' 
};

var new_obj = {};
for(key in obj){
    key.replace(/([^\[]+)\['([^\]]+)'\]/g, function($0, $1, $2){
            new_obj[$1] = new_obj[$1] || {};
        new_obj[$1][$2] = obj[key];
    })
}

console.log(new_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the popular node.js framework [Express](http://expressjs.com/), it is as simple as:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/foo', function(req, res, next) {
    // Echo the POST body
    res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Testing with curl:

```
curl -d foo=1 -d foo=2 localhost:3000/foo
```

Similar to in PHP, `req.body.foo` will be an array with all the foos you posted.

**Edit:** The `querystring` module is indeed what Express uses internally. If you need to accept file uploads, use formidable as Jan Jongboom suggests. Otherwise, here's basically how you would do it with just node:

```
var http = require('http'),
    qs = require('querystring');

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var buffer = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf-8');
    req.on('data', function(data) {
        buffer += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        var body = qs.parse(buffer);
    });
});
```

Comment: appreciated, any way to do this without express ? I don't want to change app structure.

Comment: I am using 'querystring' module.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't address multi depth brackets (i.e.  user[3][name])

Answer (score 0):

Check out [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) it can parse any form you give it. It's also the module that connect and express use to parse the form data.