# Get dynamic request params in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I construct an array says I have dynamic DOM like below?

```
<input type="hidden" name="file1" value="1.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="file2" value="2.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="file3" value="3.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="file4" value="4.jpg">
..
..
and so on
```

One way to do it is save an input that calculate the length of my file, like `req.body.number_of_file` then later on I can loop through that.

Is there any alternative to it?

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are consistently and consecutively numbered, as in your example, I would go for:

```
<input type="hidden" name="files" value="4"> <!-- or 5, 6, 42, etc. -->
```

Otherwise, try having your inputs be part of an input array:

```
<input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="1.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="2.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="3.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="4.jpg">
```

Node.js doesn't support input arrays; here's another question with some tips about that: [node.js form elements array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906913/node-js-form-elements-array)